# Problem getting expression of formula to compile

Tags: equations, compiling

I am trying to write a line of a formula as follows:

```
{\emph{P}($\emph{c}\mid\emph{d}$) =} \emph{P}(\emph{c})\prod \textsubscript{\emph{w}\in$\emph{d}}\emph{P}($\emph{w}\mid\emph{c}$) \textsuperscript{\emph{n}\textsubscript{\emph{wd}}}
```

Which should produce:

[image]

Yet upon compiling this LaTeX, I get:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.658 ...\mid\emph{d}$) =} \emph{P}(\emph{c})\prod
                                                   \textsubscript{\emph{w}\i...

?
```

I am not using the `formula` package because it is not something I know and this is the existing code I have to maintain.

Can anyone suggest why?

Comment: Formula package? Do you mean `amsmath`? You should use an introductory book on `LaTeX`, perhaps

Comment: When I get the chance. This is what I have for now.

Comment: What do  the $P$s for? Conditional probabilities?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: There  does seem to be an old `formula` package, dating back to 1998, used to typeset physical units, the TeX Catalogue says…

Comment: @Bernard: Never heard of it

Comment: @Christian Hupfe: Neither did I until I checked the Catalogue. I suppose it's superseded by `siuntx`. The documentation is in German.

Comment: @Bernard: Oh my, that's old, but it's not related for displaying the conditional probabilities. And he confuses differential quotient with a quotient of differences

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I had no idea *a priori*. Just wondered. But it might as well be inner products or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without **any** formula package (;-))

```
 \documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  P(c\mid d) = P(c) \prod_{w\in d} P(w\mid c)^{n_{wd}}
\end{equation}

Inline:   $P(c\mid d) = P(c) \prod_{w\in d} P(w\mid c)^{n_{wd}}$

or display-style

\[   P(c\mid d) = P(c) \prod_{w\in d} P(w\mid c)^{n_{wd}} \]


And here again with \verb!\mathcal!:

\[ \mathcal{P}(c\mid d) = \mathcal{P}(c) \prod\nolimits_{w\in d} \mathcal{P}(w\mid c)^{n_{wd}} \]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The only problem I have here is that the characters `w \in d` should be to the right of `\prod`. Can that be done?

Comment: Yes, using `\textstyle`, but this looks weird, `\prod\nolimits` is better

Comment: @Mico: Yes, thanks. Forgot about that `\nolimits`

Comment: I guess the math style complainers will come anyway ;-) The code works -- contrary to the version by the O.P. ;-)

Comment: @MrMorgan When the product sign is in display math mode, it is customary to place the condition below it, for better clarity; when the formula is inline, the condition is placed to the side.

Comment: Thanks to the respondents. Does anyone know how to get a small prime symbol in subscript?